Not able to install yaks on aks cluster
Trying to install below version
https://github.com/citrusframework/yaks/releases/tag/v0.19.0
Error:
$ yaks install

Tried installing via image as well



I was able to install yaks via this command
yaks install --olm=false

To install yaks on AKS, follow the below steps-
download the setup as per your OS
extract it
if linux, tar -xzf yaks-0.20.0-202404150253-linux-64bit.tar.gz
give executable permission chmod +x yaks
move the YAKS CLI binary to a directory that is in your PATH.
example-
 sudo mv yaks /usr/local/bin/

and install.
If Windows, then simply download and extract and follow the steps below-
here I am doing it on windows so downloaded the windows version, extracted it and updated the path in the environment variable.

Open the Environment Variables window again.
Find the Path variable under System variables
Edit the Path.
Click on New and add the path where you extracted yak
Click OK to save your changes and close all remaining windows by clicking OK again.
Open a new PowerShell window fresh
Check PATH again $Env:PATH -split ';'
Yes your path is available.
set it up on AKS, login to your aks

kubectl config current-context

az aks get-credentials --resource-group <YourResourceGroup> --name <YourClusterName>

 yaks install -n <choice of namespace>

Done


Thanks for answering. I was able to install yaks via this command
yaks install --olm=false
